# Rendering a dashboard with reusable components

Tags: reactjs

I have to render several tabs on my dashboard, where I can navigate between them. Each tab must be reusable. In my sample code, I have 2 tabs and if I click on a tab, the matching tab renders. I just don't know if I am reasoning in the right way. How can I do this? My current Code is this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

function SelectTab(props) {
  var tabs = ['Overview', 'Favorites'];
  return (
    <ul>
      {tabs.map(function(tab){
        return (
          <li key={tab} onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, tab)}>
            {tab}
          </li>
        )
      }, this)}
    </ul>
  )
}
function Content(props) {
  return (
    <div>Content {props.tab}</div>
  )
}
export default class MainContent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'Overview'
    }
    this.updateTab = this.updateTab.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTab(this.state.selectedTab);
  }
  updateTab(tab){
    this.setState(function(){
      return {
        selectedTab: tab
    }
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectTab selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab} onSelect={this.updateTab}/>
        <Content tab={this.state.selectedTab}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You did almost good. But I would rather render `Content` in `SelectTab` component as its already getting `selectedTab` prop, this way you can render specific content based on that prop. Also:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTab(this.state.selectedTab);
}
```

is not necessary as state is already set.

Refactored example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function SelectTab(props) {
  var tabs = ['Overview', 'Favorites'];
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {tabs.map(function (tab) {
          return (
            <li key={tab} onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, tab)}>
              {tab}
            </li>
          )
        }, this)}
      </ul>
      <Content tab={props.selectedTab}/>
    </div>
  )
}

function Content(props) {
  return <div>Content {props.tab}</div>
}

export default class MainContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'Overview'
    };
    this.updateTab = this.updateTab.bind(this);
  }

  updateTab(tab) {
    this.setState(function () {
      return {
        selectedTab: tab
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <SelectTab selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab} onSelect={this.updateTab}/>;
  }
}
```

Also keep in mind that with proper babel-transpiling your code could be much simplified like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const TABS = ['Overview', 'Favorites'];
const SelectTab = ({ selectedTab, onSelect }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {
        TABS.map(
          tab => <li key={tab} onClick={() => onSelect(tab)}> {tab} </li>
        )
      }
    </ul>
    <Content tab={selectedTab}/>
  </div>
);


const Content = ({ tab }) => <div>Content {tab}</div>;

export default class MainContent extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedTab: 'Overview'
  };

  updateTab = tab => this.setState(() => ({ selectedTab: tab }));

  render() {
    return <SelectTab selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab} onSelect={this.updateTab}/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to create a Tab bar, to be more specific

Comment: @IcaroRegoFernandes then your question should be specific.

Comment: Sorry, next time I will. I'm kinda new on these things.